# How to iterate over JSON list and select one element

Tags: json, list

Say I have a list of names with ids, in JSON:

```
(let ((json-object-type 'plist))
  (setq mylist (json-read-from-string "[{\"name\": \"Adam\", \"id\": \"1\"},
                                        {\"name\": \"Eve\", \"id\": \"2\"}]")))
```

I want to find out Adam's id.  How do I do that?

I'm currently trying

```
(dolist (person  mylist)
  (when (equal "Adam" (plist-get person :name))
    (setq person_id (plist-get person :id)))
  )
```

But this raises *setq: Wrong type argument: listp, [(:id "1" :name "Adam") (:id "2" :name "Eve")]*

Comment: You're passing a vector to a macro expecting a list...

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me towards the easiest (read as 'minimal change') solution, just converting the vector to a list using (mapchar 'identity ...)

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be `(append vector nil)`.

Comment: Could you add your own comment as a solution and/or accept one of the others if it worked for you?

Answer (score 6):

You can instruct `json-read-from-string` to parse JSON arrays as elisp lists by let binding `json-array-type` to list like so

```el
(let ((json-object-type 'plist)
      (json-array-type 'list))
  (setq mylist (json-read-from-string "[{\"name\": \"Adam\", \"id\": \"1\"},
                                        {\"name\": \"Eve\", \"id\": \"2\"}]")))                                 {\"name\": \"Eve\", \"id\": \"2\"}]")))
```

`mylist` now would be an elisp list which you manipulate/traverse using existing list functions.

Answer (score 0):

Working with vectors is a tad bothersome as only the most basic operations have been implemented.  Here's a handcoded loop:

```
(let* ((json-object-type 'plist)
       (vector (json-read-from-string "[{\"name\": \"Adam\", \"id\": \"1\"},
                                        {\"name\": \"Eve\", \"id\": \"2\"}]"))
       (i 0)
       value)
  (while (and (< i (length vector)) (not value))
    (let ((person (aref vector i)))
      (when (string= (plist-get person :name) "Adam")
        (setq value (plist-get person :id))))
    (setq i (1+ i)))
  value)
```